# How to program a Sort feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on Ruby on rails 2.3.4 and I'm trying to develop a Sort feature on my website's search page(its url is /anuncios/buscar).

What I tried is to create a "map" on routes file:

```
map.search_filter_relevance "/anuncios/buscar", :controller => 'announcements', :action => 'search_filter_relevance'
```

Then, I wrote this on the view:

```
<%=  link_to 'M&Aacute;S RELEVANTES', search_filter_relevance_path(@announcements) %>
```

And finally, I created a method in the controller, as is specified on the routes' line:

```
  def search_filer_relevance
    raise params.inspect
  end
```

First of all, as I'm sorting search results, I'd like to keep them in their public variable called @announcements. Please help me do this.

An the other thing is that when I click the link I get an error due its trying to access the Show action instead of search_filter_relevance as specified in routes. Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

It seems that I have a conflict between some of my lines at routes.rb file.

There more than one line that calls the same path. For example:

```
  map.search "/anuncios/buscar", :controller => 'announcements', :action => 'search'
  map.power_search "/anuncios/buscar", :controller => 'announcements', :action => 'power_search'
  map.search_filter_relevance "/anuncios/buscar", :controller => 'announcements', :action => 'search_filter_relevance'
```

So if I click the Sort link I'll be redirected to the Search action instead of the 'search_filter_relevance'. But, if I change its path to another thing(for example: "anuncios/buscar_2") it will execute the action I want but it will ask me to create a template "buscar_2" for that, and I don't want to do this.

I just want to have a link button that when is clicked a table is sorted. That's all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the route helper method is `search_filter_relevance_path`.

You can run `rake routes` to see all of the routes and methods you have set up.

As for the sorting, [searchlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) already exists, so I'd have to have a really good reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Replacing "_url" with "_path" does not solve the issue. It keeps asking for Show action.

Comment: Did you post the wrong code? The example you have above doesn't use _url at all.

Comment: jdl: that must be due to the many things I've tried to accomplish this, and maybe I deleted the "_url" syntax accidentally. Adding it or "_path" is not solving the problem.

Comment: Alright. Go ahead and post your real code, and the relevant output from "rake routes". It's hard to help you debug code without being able to see it.

Comment: Having editing that. I've wrote everything as I have it on my website. Any help will be appreciated.